# jQuery Dialog box is not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I use dialog box when inserting a note. The dialog box is working on the local but when i upload to the live site it is not working anymore.

The JS library is there.

There is an error message  "jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog is not a function"

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Note" style="text-align: left; display:none;">
```

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: It looks like you forgot to paste the HTML

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965026/jquery-ui-dialog-dialog-not-a-function-error) post looks very similar to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should include jquery-ui.js to your page before you can use this function 
and be aware that the modal dialog should be included in your jquery-ui file