# TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function on devserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a master page in which i included following css/js:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/jquery-ui.css">
```

this is my function which i used to open a popup, I am passing few parameter to load popup.

```
function planDataInputPopup(dialogId, formID, actionName, popHeight, popWidth, paramData) {

$(dialogId).dialog({
    autoOpen : true,width : popWidth,modal : true,dialogClass: 'no-close',
    draggable: true, resizable: true, position: [306,105],
    buttons : {
        "Create" : function() {
                if(document.getElementById("dropDownCounter").value != null){
                    document.getElementById("dropDownCounter").value=dropDownCounter+1;
                } 
                document.getElementById("inputPopupMode").value=true;
                if(paramData == 'false'){
                    submitInputFormUsingAjax(formID,actionName,"#inputFormMainDiv");
                }else{
                    submitMultipartFormUsingAjax(formID,actionName,"#inputFormMainDiv");
                }
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(this).remove();
                //$(this).dialog("destroy");
        },

        Cancel : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $(this).remove();
            //$(this).dialog("destroy");
            return false;
        }
    },

    close : function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $(this).remove();
        //$(this).dialog("destroy");
    }
});  }
```

Above code is working fine in local, bur when i deployed on development server i'm getting exception `TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function` or sometime for "$(this).dialog("destroy")";

dialog should close but it is not happening on dev server.

what mistake i'm doing not getting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery UI dialog - \*Dialog not a function\* error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965026/jquery-ui-dialog-dialog-not-a-function-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function` is [the error you get out of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError), when you have not loaded `jqueryui`. Other browsers have equivalent errors. You can

(1) Double check that your devserver has a working and non-firewalled connection to `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js`, or better yet -

(2) Download [a minified jquery-ui.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js) and include it in a `third-party` or `lib` directory on your server, then source it from there (this is commonly seen practice).

---

ALSO: Calling `$(this).remove()` also calls `.destroy()`, which in turn calls `.close()` if the dialog is still open. Both of these lines:

```
$(this).dialog("close");
$(this).dialog("destroy");
```

are completely unnecessary, and you can safely delete them without changing any behaviour. Essentially you're making calls to `.destroy()` on two consecutive lines, so the second call will result in an *uninitialised* error

Comment: Thanks for reply, How can i check my devserver has a non-firewalled connection to "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js", I don't have access of devserver. only,I can commit my code which automatically deployed on dev server on certain interval.                                                    
I just want to close popup after operation is done, but it is not happening..:(

Comment: @amitkumar12788 When you get that error, all javascript on your page stops running, which is a much bigger problem than *just closing the popup*. With regards to which, try what I suggested in the second part: use only `$(this).remove()`